# Why does the permute layer fail with in-place operation?

Tags: caffe

I tried to use `Permute` layer with intel caffe, the codes with in-place operation failed with wrong `top` blob shape:

```
layer {
  name: "conv4_3_norm_mbox_conf_perm"
  type: "Permute"
  bottom: "per_blob"
  top: "per_blob"
  permute_param {
    order: 0
    order: 2
    order: 3
    order: 1
  }
}
```

which succeeded with different `bottom`, `top` name.

Why does the in-place operation fail?

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, values are messed up during permutation. To swap two variables, you need a temporary buffer (unless you use XOR tricks or something).